# Share ASP.NET Core Identity application cookie in conjunction with Blazor Components (Server-side)

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I am working with an existing ASP.NET Core 6 project, configured with out-of-the-box ASP.NET Core Identity and application cookies as the auth mechanism.

Currently I am tasked with exploring how easy it would be for us to slowly introduce Blazor Components to this project; and I've got a working PoC with Blazor Server running.

However, those Blazor components seem totally unaware of the authenticated user (which I think is due to the nature of the websocket connection setup)

I wonder if there is a way for me to write Blazor Server components in this particular setup where http requests from inside those components are authenticated the exact same way as the old "MVC way" application using the cookie or something similar without completing turning the identity setup upside down (this is a critical application and the goal of the PoC is to introduce things with as little impact as possible).

Thank you.

Comment: Please show  the codes you've tried ,Blazor is based on signalr ,it makes no sense to share the cookie ,and acces the current user with  AuthenticationStateProvider instead of HttpContext.User

Comment: You could check this document related :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio